# Mongo db, add a field similar to SQL's SELECT *

Tags: mongodb, select, aggregate

I need to add a "calculated" field to a mongo result, but the projection removes all the data leaving onlt the converted field.

Is there a way to `SELECT *, operation(cola,colB) AS NEW_COL FROM T` in mongo?

sample data:

```
COL_A COL_B COL_C
a     1     1581292800000
b     2     1583884800000
c     3     1616284800000
```

I want a query that keeps the first columns and add COL_C with unix time

```
COl_A COL_B COL_C          COL_D       
a     1     1581292800000  10/02/2020    
b     2     1583884800000  11/03/2020  
c     3     1616284800000  21/03/2021
```

EDIT: fixed timestamps to reflect actual data (updated to 13 digits)

In sql I'll do something like:

```sql
SELECT *, DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(COL_C)) AS COL_D
FROM T;
```

In mongo I can have a table with the converted field, but I'm not able to get all the unchanged data

```
db.getCollection('T').aggregate([  
{  
    "$project":{
        "COL_D": {
            "$add": [new Date(0), "$COL_C" ]
                  }
             // also "COL_D": new Date($COL_C) gives the same result
               }
}
])
```

EDIT: BSON data

```
/*1*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ec61e577d30a51a840f564a"),
    "sessionId" : "20cbd618-e109-42be-aac6-1398284e9ef3",
    "timestamp" : NumberLong(1590042199043),
    "value": "hi"
    "events" : [ 
        {
            "eventType" : "start",
            "timestamp2" : NumberLong(1590042198969)

        }, 
        {
            "eventType" : "stop",
            "timestamp2" : NumberLong(1590042199572)

        }
    ],

    "updated" : true,

}

/*2*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ec61eca7d30a51a840f564c"),
    "sessionId" : "00000000-9D5850C1-E3E8-4EB7-8EBE-9E94E373CEBA",
    "timestamp" : NumberLong(1590042314163) /*COL_C*/
    "value": "lo"
    "events" : [ 
        {
            "eventType" : "start",
            "timestamp2" : NumberLong(1590042314134)

        }, 
        {
            "eventType" : "update",
            "timestamp2" : NumberLong(1590042316217)

        }, 
        {
            "eventType" : "stop",
            "timestamp2" : NumberLong(1590042316234)

        }
    ]

    },
    "updated" : true,

}
```

Actual BSON output:

```
/*1*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ec61e577d30a51a840f564a"),
    "sessionId" : "20cbd618-e109-42be-aac6-1398284e9ef3",
    "timestamp" : NumberLong(1590042199043), /*COL_C*/
    "value": "hi"
    "events" : [ 
        {
            "eventType" : "start",
            "timestamp2" : NumberLong(1590042198969)

        }, 
        {
            "eventType" : "stop",
            "timestamp2" : NumberLong(1590042199572)

        }
    ],

    "updated" : true,
    "COL_D" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z")/*Expected: 2020-05-21T06:23:19.043Z */
}

/*2*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ec61eca7d30a51a840f564c"),
    "sessionId" : "00000000-9D5850C1-E3E8-4EB7-8EBE-9E94E373CEBA",
    "timestamp" : NumberLong(1590042314163) /*COL_C*/
    "value": "lo"
    "events" : [ 
        {
            "eventType" : "start",
            "timestamp2" : NumberLong(1590042314134)

        }, 
        {
            "eventType" : "update",
            "timestamp2" : NumberLong(1590042316217)

        }, 
        {
            "eventType" : "stop",
            "timestamp2" : NumberLong(1590042316234)

        }
    ]

    },
    "updated" : true,
    "COL_D" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z") /* expected: 2020-05-21T06:25:14.163Z */
}
```

The value "COL_D" is the "UTC" calculated from "timestamp"

Comment: Show us your sample data properly as Mongo BSON document rather than SQL column style. NoSQL is not SQL - if you work with MongoDB you have to get used to JSON/BSON style documents, even though it is a bit annoying in the beginning.

Comment: added BSON data

Comment: You put `new Date(0)` which is of course `1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`$toDate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/) available from MongoDB v4.2

```
db.getCollection('T').aggregate([{  
  "$addFields":{
    "COL_D": {
      "$toDate": "$COL_C"
    }
  }
}])
```

For lower versions, I have actually tried your version (with `$addFields` instead of `$project`) and it should work.

```
db.getCollection('T').aggregate([{  
  "$addFields":{
    "COL_D": {
      "$add": [new Date(0), "$COL_C"]
    }
  }
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $addFields: {
         COL_D: new Date("$COL_C")
      }
   }
])
```

Note, in MongoDB/JavaScript `Date` values are given as **Milli**seconds from `1970-01-01 00:00:00Z`, so you may have to use `new Date({ $multiply: [ "$COL_C", 1000 ] })`

Comment: Nice: it adds the column, anyway dates are all 1/1/1970 (with and without multiplication)

Comment: Verify your input data, I  get `COL_D: new Date(1000*1581292800) -> "COL_D" : ISODate("2020-02-10T01:00:00.000+0100")`

Comment: It's odd: pasting the value it works, inside the query on the table it does not

Comment: `new Date("$COL_C")` is not valid because javascript will try to evaluate `new Date()` with the input `"$COL_C"` as string. Similarly `new Date({ $multiply: [ "$COL_C", 1000 ] })` is also invalid because it's evaluating the object.